# Connecting Oracle 12c OSB to Oracle 9i Database is having an intermittent connection error

Tags: oracle-12c, oracle-database

After upgrading OSB to 12C, all JCA connections to 9i Database is having an error with:

```
The invocation resulted in an error: Invoke JCA outbound service failed with
connection error, exception: com.bea.wli.sb.transports.jca.JCATransportException.
WSIF JCA Execute of operation 'select' failed due to: DBReadInteractionSpec
Execute Failed Exception.
```

I might be missing in any configuration when we upgraded to 12c but at this point, I've no clue. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Tried Work-around**: We've tried doing a work-around by invoking Java applications that invoke stored procedures in 9i database but it's causing several other issues instead.